# Python regex read /etc/resolv.conf and return ip address only, think its almost there,

Tags: python, regex, linux, ip

I have been writing a python script and I am having a problem with a certain function, its supposed to open the /etc/resolv.conf file, read it line by line and return only the ip addresses. Although it appears to be finding the ip address ,it's not telling me then only what part of memory there in any idea how to get it to tell me the matching string itself.

Here's the function:

```
def get_resolv():
    nameservers=[]
    rconf = open("/etc/resolv.conf","r")
    line = rconf.readline()
    while line:
        try:
            ip = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line)


        except:
            ip = "none set"
        print ip
        nameservers.append(ip)
        line= rconf.readline()

    return nameservers
```

heres the ouput when called:

```
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb76964b8>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7696db0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re.search` is returning a [Match Object](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects).  This is an object which has a number of attributes which tell you about the match.

To get the whole matched text use `ip.group(0)` or `ip.group()`.

Also `re.search` doesn't throw an exception if there is no match, and instead returns `None`.  So your code should look something like:

```
ip = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line)

if ip is None:
    ip = "none set"
```

Comment: yep changed line to this 
ip = re.search(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",line).group()
and now works perfect thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Shutupsquare - That's working but perhaps isn't ideal.  When you have no match `ip` will be `None` and then when you try to run the `group()` method you'll get an exception which your `try except` will catch.  IMHO it would preferable to check if `ip` is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
>>> data=open("/etc/resolv.conf").read().split()
>>> for item in data:
...     if len( item.split(".") ) == 4:
...          print item
...
192.168.0.1
```

Comment: just checked this and it also works perfectly for what i want thank you very much

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer because it's more of a Pythonic "duck typing" approach and without regex. If the string LOOKS like an IP, then it is an IP. Only an additional test `all(isinstance(i, int) for i in item.split("."))` could improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Python3

```
def get_resolvers():
"""
if using WSL will access /etc/resolv.conf and parse the host address
:return: str ip address
"""
resolvers = []
try:
    with open("/etc/resolv.conf", encoding='utf-8') as resolvconf:
        for line in resolvconf.readlines():
            line = line.split('#', 1)[0].rstrip()
    if 'nameserver' in line:
        resolvers.append(line.split()[1])
    return resolvers[0] if len(resolvers) > 0 else "127.0.0.1"
except Exception as err:
    return "127.0.0.1"
```